# Google form to spreadsheet, create new column

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I created a Google form and a spreadsheet associated that form. On the spreadsheet there are two columns by default. A is Timestamp and B is Untitled question. Now I want to create another column in C that counts the form response's number (like the spreadsheet rows on the left) automatically when somebody send a submission.

Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: [Comment in the original answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/60315/88163) by @ghozx `Perhaps you need to do something with the number in column C?`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking another question since the answer to your question is to simply look at the row number and subtract 1: that is, use the formula

```
=ROW()-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `=ROW()-1` as was proposed in the [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/60315/88163) by @ghozx. It's worth to say that this will require to fill down the formula manually or by a script after one or more responses be submitted.

An alternative is to use the following formula in cell C2:

```
=Filter(Row(B2:B)-1,Not(isblank(B2:B)))
```

The above formula will return an array that will be of the same size of the number of responses, displaying the response number for each response. In other words, when a respondent submit a new response, the related row in column c will automatically display the response number.

Comment: Shorter version: `=Filter(Row(B2:B)-1,Len(B2:B))`